# Symfony - API Platform - Vich Uploader & vulnerability issues

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com, vichuploaderbundle

Good morning,
I'm trying to develop a smartphone application connected to an API Platform API.
I need the option to upload some files from the application.
I cannot trust those who send files.
I've followed the https://api-platform.com/docs/core/file-upload/ guidlines. Thus, I can't see how to prevent a CWE-434 vulnerability (**Unrestricted Upload of File with Dangerous Type**, https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/434.html). I've done it myself on my system, so the vulnerability works with my configuration. I cannot believe that it was forgotten from the vichuploaderbundle. It must be something else, but I can't figure out what.
Should I write my own image handler, or is there a way to use vichuploaderbundle with safety ?

Comment: have you opened an issue "also" to the maintainers of the main Vick's repository on github?

Comment: No I haven't, I'm doing it richt away !

Comment: So I've posted the issue and for image upload it seems symfony constraint Image does the trick : [github 1](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/issues/1136) [github 2](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/issues/1129)